# How to get the permanent link in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I'm writing a plugin to add some extra contents that contain the permanent link to the (single) post.

```
function abcd_add_contents($content) {
    $extra_content = the_permalink();

    if (is_single()) {
         $content .= $extra_content;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'abcd_add_contents');
```

`the_permalink()` does not work. How can I obtain the permanent link information of the current post in this plugin function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

globalize `$post` to get the current post's data. also, you want `get_permalink`, which *returns* the permalink, rather than `the_permalink`, which directly *echoes* the permalink.

```
function abcd_add_contents($content) {

    if (is_single()) {
        global $post;
        $extra_content = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $content .= $extra_content;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'abcd_add_contents');
```

Answer (score 1):

`the_permalink` function echoes the post permalink. What you want to use is [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function, which returns post permalink for use as variable.